# updating two frames with one "a href" link

Tags: javascript, html

I have two links in my code:

```
<li> 
    <a href="menu/zakChar/zakCharMenu.html" target="frameLeft"></a>
    <a href ="view/zakChar.html" target="frame">Základné charakteristiky</a>
</li>
```

The first link update frame "frameLeft", second update frame "frame". I want to create one link instead of these two links. When user click on this link, it should be update both these frames("frameLeft" and also "frame" at once). How to do it, please?

Comment: Create a function that, when clicked (or any other event) updates the source url for both frames.

Comment: It can not be done without using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may do something like:

```
<a href="menu/zakChar/zakCharMenu.html" target="frameLeft" onClick="top.frame.location='view/zakChar.html';">Základné charakteristiky</a>
```

credits by: [HTML frames](http://www.htmlhelp.com/faq/html/frames.html#frame-update2)

Working Example [here](https://github.com/rmjoia/multipleFramesUpdate)

Comment: this doesnt work, what exactly mean top.frame.location ? :) This code only update frame "frameLeft", not "frame".

Comment: top = target like (new, self, main), frame = frame name, location = url

Comment: this doesnt work :( is there any other solution? :) this error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'location' of undefined

Comment: I've setup here an example, and it works.. I'm pushing it to git, please stand by